# how to separate a factor without whitespace in R?

Tags: r, split

I want to separate a factor with 14 rows, each row is like `"cg17205324 (Adolescence)"`

I tried `strsplit()`, but always ended up with `"cg17205324 "`.

Googled various methods to clean the tailing `whitespace` but did not work, because it is a `factor` rather than `string`.

any tips?

Comment: What is your desired output? "cg17205324" "(Adolescence)" or "cg" "17205324" "(Adolescence)" or something else? when you tried `strsplit`, why did it not work?

Comment: using `trimws(factor('cg17205324 '))` worked perfectly for me. It converts the result to a string but you can always just wrap it in as.factor() like so  `as.factor(trimws(factor('cg17205324 ')))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
 "cg17205324 (Adolescence)" -> outp
 strsplit(outp," ") # " " serves as space and separate the two strings 
[[1]]
[1] "cg17205324"    "(Adolescence)"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `scan`

```
scan(text=str1, what ="", quiet=TRUE)
#[1] "cg17205324"    "(Adolescence)"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "cg17205324 (Adolescence)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- "cg17205324 (Adolescence)"

b <- strsplit(a, " ")
b

#[[1]]
#[1] "cg17205324"    "(Adolescence)"
```